# Discord Node js Canvas Error: Unsupported image type

Tags: node.js, canvas, discord, bots

I have been trying to fix this thing for over a week now, searching in google and youtube for this damn error and no solution have been found. I know Im at first days of node js so my code might be not perfect, but the canvas one were taken from people that did tutorials and I have try as many of them but the result is always the same error no matter what. Apparently the error going away if I remove every related displayAvatarURL code, which sucks because I can't use the user avatar in my welcome image. I have try to change formats, changing code, changing background image with a black one made with Gimp (not that matter because the problem seem is avatar)and removed background to check again. Nothing work. The bot will crash ALWAYS as soon a real user join probably because the avatar image and it DOESN'T crash when invite a bot for testing (because it doesnt have custom avatars apparently?). Thank you for the help.

Error:

> node:events:505
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ^

Error: Unsupported image type
at setSource (C:********\Desktop\lolinya_bot_js\node_modules\canvas\lib\image.js:91:13)
at C:********\Desktop\lolinya_bot_js\node_modules\canvas\lib\image.js:59:11
at C:********\Desktop\lolinya_bot_js\node_modules\simple-get\index.js:97:7
at IncomingMessage. (C:********\Desktop\lolinya_bot_js\node_modules\simple-concat\index.js:88:13)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:641:28)
at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:539:35)
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:384:10)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:85:21)

Index.js:

````
const {
  Client,
  GatewayIntentBits,
  Routes,
  // InteractionType,
} = require('discord.js');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const fs = require('node:fs');
// const { Console } = require('node:console');
const generateImage = require('../generateImage.js');

dotenv.config();

// - CONFIG TOKEN, CLIENT AND GUILD ID
const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN;
const CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
const GUILD_ID = process.env.GUILD_ID;
const WELCOME_ID = process.env.WELCOME_ID;

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
});

// - CONFIG SLASH COMMANDS -
const commands = [];
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./src/commands')
  .filter(file => file.endsWith('js'));
client.slashcommands = new Discord.Collection();

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  client.slashcommands.set(command.data.name, command);
  commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(TOKEN);

// - CLIENT EMITTERS -
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`${client.user.tag} has logged in.`);
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (member) => {
  const img = await generateImage(member);
  member.guild.channels.cache.get(WELCOME_ID).send({
    content: `<@${member.id}> Welcome to the server!`,
    files: [img]
  });
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
    const slashcmd = client.slashcommands.get(interaction.commandName);
    await slashcmd.run({ client, interaction });
});

// - INITIALIZE THE BOT AND ALSO REFRESH SLASH COMMANDS LIST -
(async () => {
  try {
    console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');
    await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(CLIENT_ID, GUILD_ID), {
      body: commands,
    });
    console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
    client.login(TOKEN);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})(); 

generateImage.js:

const { createCanvas, loadImage, registerFont } = require('canvas');
registerFont('./font/Cat paw.ttf', {family: 'neko'});
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { AttachmentBuilder } = require('discord.js');

const background = "https://i.imgur.com/VZblp7S.jpg";

const dim = {
    height: 675,
    width: 1200,
    margin: 50,
}

const av = {
    size: 256,
    x: 480,
    y: 170,
}

const generateImage = async (member) => {
    let canvas = await createCanvas(dim.width, dim.height);
    let ctx = await canvas.getContext('2d');
    let username = member.user.username;
    let discrim = member.user.discriminator;
    // let avatarURL = member.displayAvatarURL({format: 'jpg', dynamic: true, size: av.size})
    // Draw the canvas for our image
    // const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(dim.width, dim.height);
    // const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const backimg = await loadImage(background);
    let x = 0 //canvas.width / 2 - backimg.width / 2;
    let y = 0 //canvas.height / 2 - backimg.height / 2;
    ctx.drawImage(backimg, x, y);

    // Draw a semi-transparent box for text readability
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)"
    ctx.fillRect(
        dim.margin,
        dim.margin,
        dim.width - 2 * dim.margin,
        dim.height - 2 * dim.margin
    ); //fillRect(posX,posY, width, height)

    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(
        av.x + av.size / 2, 
        av.y + av.size / 2, 
        av.size / 2, 0, 
        Math.PI * 2, 
        false
    ); //arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle, clockwise)
    ctx.clip();
    let avimg = await loadImage(member.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' }));
    ctx.drawImage(avimg, av.x, av.y);
    ctx.restore();

    // Config our welcome text
    ctx.fillStyle = 'pink';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';

    // Draw the welcome text
    ctx.font = '80px Cat paw';
    ctx.fillText("Welcome to the Server", dim.width / 2, dim.margin + 70)

    // Draw the username text
    ctx.font = '100px Cat paw';
    ctx.fillText(`${username} #${discrim}`, dim.width / 2, dim.height - dim.margin - 125);

    // Draw the server name text
    ctx.font = '40px Cat paw';
    ctx.fillText(`You are the member #${member.guild.memberCount}!`, dim.width / 2, dim.height - dim.margin - 50);

    let attachment = new AttachmentBuilder(canvas.toBuffer(), { name: 'welcome.png' })
    return attachment;
}

module.exports = generateImage ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the `unsupported image type` error with the avatar URL -> On discord.js v14 `format` was replaced with `extension` so you'll have to change that

Comment: Huh.. I mean what.. I asked to quite few ppl and showed code and no one told me about that? Thank you! Tho now I switched to the other module, but good to know for the future.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, it comes from the fact that

```
member.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' })
```

returns a `.webp` instead of returning a `.png`. It's strange, maybe it's bug from Discord.js v14.
I have found an ugly fix:

```
let avimg = await loadImage("https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/" + member.id + "/" > + member.avatar + ".png");
```

Comment: So it seem I have try another canvas npm module, in this case is @napi-rs/canvas, added undici and the line `const attachment = new AttachmentBuilder(await canvas.encode("png"), {
    name: "profile-image.png",
  }); ` and the problem disappeared. What changed is that canvas.encode is the key to make it work apparently?